# Change color in Shiny Dashboard for menuSubItem

Tags: r, submenu, shinydashboard

I have a problem with the colors for menu subItems.
The color spreads first over all the subitems (picture 1), the font color is grey.
And when I hover the top-menu-item is black (picture 2).

What works so far is changing the background color of the submenu:

```
.skin-red .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .treeview-menu {
    background-color: #FDFDFD;
}
```

I tried variations of:

```
.skin-red .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .treeview-menu a {
    color: #8e44ad;
}   

.skin-red .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .treeview-menu a:hover {
    color: #8e44ad;
}
```

With submenu selected:

[image: Submenu selected]

With submenu selected and hovered in this area:

[image: Submenu selected and hovered in this area]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've improved text and code-formatting, embedded images (for better readabilty and hopefully more answers)

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm new in this community and also in R :)
I can't do it on my own because i need 15 points or sth. for embedded images ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this questions is quite dated, but I just came across this question while trying to solve the same problem. What worked in my case was adding the following tags about `.treeview-menu` in the `dashboardSidebar`section.

```
dashboardSidebar(width = 260,
    # ...sidebar items and other tags I need
        tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .treeview-menu li.active a {background-color: #1E282C !important;}")),
        tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .treeview-menu li:hover a {background-color: #1E282C !important;}"))
    # ...some other tags I need
)
```

I hope this helps.